# Swift: Add ViewController inside UIView

Tags: swift

I created a launcher to display a UIView from the bottom of the screen, half size of the window.

I want to display a UIViewController inside this bottom UIView. I tried the below:

```
class CardLauncher: NSObject {

   lazy var containerView: UIView = {
       let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        return view
    }()

  func showCard(withID id: Int) {
     let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        if let window = keyWindow { 
            window.addSubview(constainerView)

            let height: CGFloat = 280
            let y = window.frame.height - height
            self.cardYPosition = y
            self.initialTouchPoint.y = window.frame.height - height
            containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: height)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.constainerView.frame.width, height: self.containerView.frame.height)
            }, completion: nil)

            let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:(#selector(self.handleGesture(_:))))
            containerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            containerView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

            // I tried this:
            let vc = AccountViewController()
            vc.view.frame = constainerView.bounds
            constainerView.addSubview(vc.view)
   }

}
```

Comment: If you want multiple `UIViewController`s on a screen, you should use Child View Controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
        let vc = AccountViewController()
        vc.view.frame = constainerView.bounds
        constainerView.addSubview(vc.view)
```

...is both illegal and pointless. You cannot "dumpster dive" by creating a view controller, grabbing its view, shoving its view into the interface somehow, and letting the view controller fall on the floor. Even if the view appears, it will have no functionality, because the view controller is gone.

One correct way to use a view controller to make a view appear in a custom way at a custom size is to *present* the view controller using a *custom transition animation* and a *custom presentation controller*. (Look at the documentation on UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, and UIPresentationController. If you want this to happen interactively in response to a gesture, you will also need to look at UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning.)

Or you can make your main view controller into a *parent view controller*. In that case you need to make the other view controller your main view controller's *child* and make certain calls to ensure a coherent parent–child relationship. (Look at the section "Implementing a Container View Controller" in the UIViewController documentation.)

Comment: After reading the documentation I have a better understanding of  "Implementing a Container View Controller" in the UIViewController documentation